# Kentico "This action is not allowed in current context"

Tags: c#, .net, content-management-system, kentico

I have a kentico 6 installation, if i go to CMSDesk, edit one particular content item (document i suppose) and try to save it i get the following error in a javascript alert: "This action is not allowed in current context". There is not much information on this error on the internet, it says that one of the parts of the page is broken, is there any way to determine which one? I get this error for ONLY ONE item, all the others are fine. Any ideas are welcome, I will provide any info needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Event log for any errors:

CMSSitemanager > Administration > Event log

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing related to this issue in event log

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently done any upgrades to the system?  This typically happens with an upgrade.  It is specifically related to JS files.  I've specifically experienced it with upgrades to major versions (6->7, 7->8, etc).  What you might do is try to clear the cache on the server and within you browser.

It can also be related to bad markup.  You might check to see if you have a `<form>` tag or other invalid markup, correct it and see if this resolves your issue.

Comment: sorry for not replying recently, there were no CMS\JS upgrades done for a LONG time

Comment: @HardLuck Have you validated your markup to ensure you only have one form tag in there and no missing tags?